# JDBC Sink Connector - how to specify a database schema in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using a JDBC Sink Connector to insert data into SQL Server. My table is called Plant and the schema is pts. So I'm trying to insert into InventoryManagement.pts.Plant.

I've set up a new user called testuserpts in SQL Server, with the default schema name set to pts. The error message that I'm getting back from Confluent is that Table "dbo"."Plant" is missing and auto-creation is disabled.

Here's my configuration for the sink connector. How do I prevent the sink from trying to connect to dbo.Plant?

```
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "name": "JdbcSinkConnector",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "topics": ["plant"],
  "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://host.docker.internal:53954;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=InventoryManagement",
  "connection.user": "testuserpts",
  "connection.password": "testpassword",
  "table.name.format": "Plant"
```

Comment: Have you tried "table.name.format": "pts.Plant" ?

Comment: Have you tried setting `catalog.pattern` and/or `schema.pattern` properties yet?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett yes I have and it still tacks on the dbo, resulting in dbo.pts.Plant.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I believe that config is only for the source connector.

Comment: @TravisCallahan, you are correct, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to get it working. The correct config is:

`"table.name.format": "InventoryManagement.pts.Plant"`

So, `<db>.<schema>.<table`

Comment: That makes sense. We have a Debezium source for SQL Server and some configuration settings require db.schema.table and some just schema.table.